# MyEtherWallet - address doesn't match

Tags: myetherwallet, addresses

Well, I'm pretty certain I' screwed, but I figured I'd ask for help just in case.

I created one, and only one wallet on MEW. I was meticulous about saving my Private Key and address correctly. I printed them both out immediately, took pictures, and logged them into a notebook.

I transferred TRX to my address: 0xA349Ec964F9814357cA14602870f55BABf44097E

The transaction was successful, as I checked on this initially by entering my address only in MEW.

I just recently to logged into MEW with my Private Key; and to my surprise, no TRX tokens and a completely different address is listed. I'm just not sure how this could have possibly happened. I'm staring at screenprints of my key and address that I used to send the TRX tokens. I'm positive I did not make any key stroke errors as I've reentered multiple times.

Anything I can do to recover my TRX? Or is it a lost cause?

Comment: Every get an answer or figure this out? I have a similar issue.

Comment: Did you save anything else, like the keystore JSON file?